# Expressjs page not rendering

Tags: node.js, express, pug

Sometimes when I load my page it simply does not render, it does not give any errors, in fact the client gets the proper response from the server (with the required static content), but I see a blank page. If I try to inspect an element on the page then everything shows up properly. I have the following middleware configuration, but I don't think that the problems are here:

```
App.app.set('views', App.appPath("app/views"))
App.app.set('view engine', 'jade');
App.app.set('view options', {
  pretty: env === 'development'
})
App.app.locals({
  constants: App.util('htmlConstants')
})

// Middlewarez
App.app.use(express.logger('dev'))
App.app.use(express.compress())
App.app.use(express.bodyParser())
App.app.use(express.methodOverride())
App.app.use(appCookieParser)
App.app.use(express.session({
    store: appRedisStore
}))
App.app.use(require('stylus').middleware(App.appPath('public')))
App.app.use(App.app.router)

if (App.env === 'development') {

App.test = function(path) {
    return App.require("app/test/" + path)
}

 App.app.use(express.static(App.appPath('public')))
} else {
 App.app.use(express.static(App.appPath('public')), {
    maxAge: settings.oneDay
})
}

App.app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.log('in error handler')
  console.log(err.message)
  next(err)
});
App.app.use(express.errorHandler());
```

Comment: Have you tried to clear cache in browser? That might be a cached empty page.

Comment: I get this behavior too.  I use jade templates and sometimes the page will show blank and if I alt-tab off the page and back the content will suddenly show up.

Answer (score -1):

Something is probably wrong with your cache.

Instead of this:

```
 App.app.use(express.static(App.appPath('public')))
} else {
 App.app.use(express.static(App.appPath('public')), {
    maxAge: settings.oneDay
})
}
```

Do this:

```
//Development only
App.app.configure('development', function() {
    app.use(express.static(App.appPath('public'));
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

//Production only
App.app.configure('production', function() {
    var threeMonths = 7884000000; //Cache time in ms
    app.use(express.static(App.appPath('public'), { maxAge: threeMonths }));
});
```

Run your application like this:

```
sudo NODE_ENV=development node app.js
```

Comment: I don't see how is this different from my current implementation.

Answer (score -1):

use console.log('variableName'); and observe the value of the variable which got data from db.

if not normal,that means you may get data from server side incorrectly!

Comment: As I said, I get all the variables, just at first it doesn't render the page. If I right click the page it works.

Comment: this may help you :[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792142/why-is-my-express-jade-app-rendering-blank-pages]